# How to make a confirm dialog <p:confirmDialog> down the page

Tags: css, primefaces

Following is the p:confirmDialog code :

```
<p:confirmDialog id="popUpData" global="true" widgetVar="popUpData"
        header="#{app['data.fail']}" styleClass="Sdialog" 
        closable="false" draggable="true">
```

Below is the CSS code :

```
.Sdialog{
    width:50% !important;
    height:20% !important;
    top : 80% !important;
}
```

Want to just move the confirmDialog a bit down. But the pop up is not coming down and the changes are not getting reflected. Can you please help me here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I try your code in pf showcase and it works fine, so it could depend on where you put that confirm dialog, or if you're using a theme. Can you post some more info?